# Returning the outputs of a nested structure

Tags: list-manipulation

Say we have a list

```
l = {{{a, b}, c}, d}
```

To which we then apply a function `F` in the following manner

```
Replace[l, x_List :> F[x], All]
```

> F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]

Is there away of extracting the outputs of each application of `F` to `l`, so that we get a list

> {F[{a,b}],F[{F[{a,b}],c}],F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}

?

Comment: Try with `Sow`+`Reap`

Answer (score 7):

Using @Kuba 's suggestion:

```
Reap[Replace[l, x_List :> Sow[F[x]], All]]
```

> ```
> {F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}], {{F[{a, b}], F[{F[{a, b}], c}], F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}}}
> ```

So to get precisely what I want

```
Reap[Replace[l, x_List :> Sow[F[x]], All]][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{F[{a, b}], F[{F[{a, b}], c}], F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I think I'd do it with `FoldList`. Like so:

```
l = {{{a, b}, c}, d};
FoldList[F[{#1, #2}] &, Flatten @ l] // Rest
```

> `{F[{a, b}], F[{F[{a, b}], c}], F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}`

Comment: That is very nice! Thank you.

Comment: @amator2357. Thanks for accepting my answer. But I don't understand why you considered it worth an acceptance but not an up-vote. You are aware, aren't you, that you can do both.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, it wasn't intentional tho, I thought that I did upvote it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @amator2357. Your welcome and thank you for the up-vote.

Answer (score 3):

Another variation:

```
Last @ Reap[l /. List -> Sow @* F @* List]
```

> {{F[{a, b}], F[{F[{a, b}], c}], F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}}

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to extract the elements with [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `F`:

```
r = Replace[l, x_List :> F[x], All];
Cases[r, _F, All]
```

> {F[{a, b}], F[{F[{a, b}], c}], F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]}